# Oracle Apex - How to Change Map Label?

Tags: xml, oracle-apex

I am using `ORACLE APEX 4.2`, in my application I am displaying Afghan Map (AnyChart) with it's Province, Now I want to change label displaying on Map.

for example, Map showing `Kabol`, I want to replace it with `Kabul`, so `Lowgar` to `Logar` too and many more...

Here is XML (Map XML) file that might need to be updated, I tried finding but failed.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone = "yes"?>
<anychart>
  <settings>
    <animation enabled="true"/>
    <no_data show_waiting_animation="False">
      <label>
        <text>#NO_DATA_MESSAGE#</text>
        <font family="Verdana" bold="yes" size="10"/>
      </label>
    </no_data>
  </settings>
  <margin left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0" />
  <charts>
    <chart plot_type="Map" name="chart_25753918635243424"> 

      <chart_settings>
        <title enabled="False" />
        <data_plot_background>
          <fill type="Solid" color="0xffffff" opacity="0" />
          <border enabled="false"/>
          <corners type="Square"/>
        </data_plot_background>

        <chart_animation type="ScaleXLeft" interpolation_type="Quadratic" show_mode="OneByOne"/>
        <controls>
          <navigation_panel enabled="True"/>
          <zoom_panel enabled="True"/>
        </controls>
      </chart_settings>
      <data_plot_settings enable_3d_mode="false">
        <map_series source="asia/afghanistan.amap" id_column="REGION_NAME" labels_display_mode="Always">
         <projection type="Mercator"  />

         <defined_map_region >
          <tooltip_settings enabled="true">
            <format><![CDATA[{%Name}{enabled:False} - {%value1}{numDecimals:0,decimalSeparator:.,thousandsSeparator:\,}]]></format>
            <font family="Tahoma" size="10" color="0x000000" />
              <position anchor="Float" valign="Top" padding="10" /> 
          </tooltip_settings>
          <label_settings enabled="true" mode="Outside" multi_line_align="Center">
            <format><![CDATA[{%Name}{enabled:False} - {%value1}{numDecimals:0,decimalSeparator:.,thousandsSeparator:\,}]]></format>
            <background enabled="false"/>
            <font family="Arial" size="10" color="0x000000" />
          </label_settings>
         </defined_map_region>
          <grid enabled="true">
            <parallels enabled="true"/>
            <meridians enabled="true"/>
            <background>
          <fill type="Solid" color="0xffffff" opacity="0" />
          <border enabled="false"/>
          <corners type="Square"/>
            </background>
          </grid>
        </map_series>

      </data_plot_settings>

#DATA#
    </chart>
  </charts>
</anychart>
```

All I up to is by any chance if we can update or replace value of %Name conditionally I can have my solution.

Or if anybody has better Solution or Idea, please share...

Answer (score 1):

You would normally just specify the ones you want to rename in a MapRegions series, linking them (by name) to the original. For example ...

```
  <data>
    <series type="MapRegions">
      <point name="Kabol" y="0">
        <attributes>
          <attribute name="newname">Kabul</attribute>
        </attributes> 
      </point>
    </series>
  </data>
```

However, your issue is that the #DATA# tag within the PL/SQL is dynamically generating the data tag and you cannot have multiple data tags. You need to:

Option 1: Intercept this and replace inside of it if this contains some custom data you are plotting. In other words, don't use #DATA#, have some PL/SQL function call instead that reads #DATA# and writes your replaced strings.

Option 2: Generate the full data set like written above with your custom data inside it in the "y" attribute. Full means all the points. All the region names that are in the file are listed on their website. This would be much easier. Just replace #DATA# above with a function that makes the entire set of points.

Option 3: You can go get yourself a SHP file of Afghanistan, put in your labels and use their map convertor to build a new .AMAP with your labels.